# Symfony 1 and Doctrine - Out of memory and Unknown relation alias exception

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a problem, which I wasn´t able to solve yet. I have an eshop, and during few steps in order form, in one of those steps I am getting an error. On the top of the website, there is a common small cart overview, showing items count and final price. It´s being showed on every page with no problems. But in one of the order steps, when rendering a template of the cart overview, the script ends with error like this:

```
<strong class="cart"><a href="/frontend_server_dev.php/shopping-cart/overview">Cart</a></strong>
        You have <strong>1 item(s)</strong> in your cart
        <br />
        Total price is <strong>
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 499646464) (tried to allocate 80 bytes) in /var/www/libs/symfony/symfony-1.4.11-patched/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Relation/Parser.php on line 237
```

So the error is triggered, when a function to retrieve total price of cart is called.

In the template it looks like this:

```
<strong><?php echo format_price($cart->getFinalPriceWithVAT()); ?></strong>
```

I don´t get it. In my opinion "Out of memory" is not the problem, sometimes it´s just a result of another problem. But if there is some problem in Doctrine, why the exception is not triggered normally? And why this error appears just in this specific order step? I did´t change anything in last weeks, the error just occured from nowhere. I tried some debugging, but with no result.

Comment: show us the implementation of `$cart->getFinalPriceWithVAT()`. Do you maybe have any cyclic relation?  what is on `Parser.php on line 237` ?

Comment: Check for typos in your table aliases, both declarations and usages.